# Android Studio Database Inspector stays in offline mode [DETACHED]

Tags: android, android-studio

The issue is when I stop app the Database Inspector goes to Offline Mode as [described here](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database) and it doesn't go to online when I run app again. The only workaround I found it is to exit Android Studio and open again. This is not convenient way when often I have to check updated data on local database.

How can I quit offline mode?

[image]

Comment: Try `Settings -> Tools -> Database Inspector -> Enable offline mode`

Comment: Yeah, it works but now sometimes it doesn't appear online, stays detached